# Dotnet CLI compilation performance is slow on console or Visual Studio 2015

Tags: compilation, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-rc2, dotnet-cli

When I migrate from DNX - RC1 to .NET Core RC2 - Dotnet CLI that encountered slow dotnet build (compilation) issue on console or VS 2015 build.

Is there any workaround to improve build performance until dotnet-cli RTM release?

Answer (score 2):

With this little information it would be quite of a challenge to give you a straight answer to your question. There are indeed performance issues, also raised in dotnet cli's github(#[3131](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3131) and #[2889](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2889)).

The performance bugs and improvements are tracked in #[2515](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2515), perhaps you could try using an internal feed once they are fixed?